# How does R know that I have no entries of a certain type

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a table where one of the variables is country of registration.

```
table(df$reg_country)
```

returns:

```
   AR    BR    ES    FR    IT
  123   202   578   642   263
```

Now, if I subset the original table to exclude one of the countries

```
df_subset<-subset(df, reg_country!='AR')
table(df_subset$reg_country)
```

returns:

```
   AR    BR    ES    FR    IT
    0   202   578   642   263
```

This second result is very surprising to me, as R seems to somehow magically know that I have removed the the entries from AR.

Why does that happen?

Does it affect the size of the second data frame (df_subset)? If 'yes' - is there a more efficient way to to subset in order to minimize the size?

Comment: Your `reg_country` variable is probably a `factor` and by subsetting it, you remove the rows, but not the defined factor levels (which include AR). And the `table` shows all defined factor levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`df$reg_country` is a factor variable, which contains the information of all possible levels in the `levels` attribute. Check `levels(df_subset$reg_country)`.

Factor levels only have a significant impact on data size if you have a huge number of them. I wouldn't expect that to be the case. However, you could use `droplevels(df_subset$reg_country)` to remove unused levels.